# Network Analysis of column from Dataset and use of stopwords

Tags: r

I've been working of a dataset but when I insert the code in I get all words such as 'in' 'and'. I was trying to remove these common words. I know I need to use the stopwords function but I am not sure where to input and it what command to use after it? I want to find the most words use to describe a listing other than 'in' 'for' 'what'

[image: Network Analysis plot]

```
nycab$name <- as.character((nycab$name))
nycab$name <- tolower(nycab$name)
    
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(nycab$name))

nycwords_dfm <- dfm(nycab$name)
head(nycwords_dfm)
wordcountnyc_dfm <- dfm_select(nycwords_dfm, pattern = topwordcount)
topwordcount <- names(topfeatures(wordcountnyc_dfm,50))
head(topwordcount)
nycword_fcm <-fcm(wordcountnyc_dfm)
head(nycword_fcm)
nycwordcount2_fcm <- fcm_select(nycword_fcm, pattern = topwordcount)
textplot_network(nycwordcount2_fcm, min_freq = 0.1, edge_alpha = 0.8, edge_size = 5)
```

Datasets in case anyone needs it -https://www.kaggle.com/dgomonov/new-york-city-airbnb-open-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using quanteda, so get rid of the tm part in your code, the corpus line.

You can use `dfm_remove` to get rid of the stopwords.

```
nycwords_dfm <- dfm(nycab$name)
# remove stopwords
nycwords_dfm <- dfm_remove(nycwords_dfm, stopwords("english"))

# rest of your code
...
```

If you need to remove more things first use tokens:

```
# remove punctuation and stopwords via tokens
nycwords_toks <- tokens(nycab$name, remove_punct = TRUE)
nycwords_toks <- tokens_remove(nycwords_toks, stopwords("english"))
nycwords_dfm <- dfm(nycwords_toks)

# rest of your code
....
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. I just have one more question. My central cluster has a ```/, - , + 1```. How would I remove this?